# Building two images using a different include directory

Tags: c, makefile

I'm looking for a solution that let me build 2 different images of a same source code, using different constant values defined in header files that are present in two directories.

To be clear, here is my directory tree :

```
program/
    configuration1/
        header1.h
        header2.h
        ...
    configuration2/
        header1.h
        header2.h
        ...
    src/
        All the source code common to both images
```

I would like the makefile to automatically build two images (called image1.out and image2.out) including the files respectively from the first and the second configuration directory.

My idea was to create 2 different rules, and to change the CFLAGS between both. In the first, the CFLAGS includes `"-I../configuration1"` and in the second, it includes `"-I../configuration2"`.
But I read this (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

> Be aware that a given prerequisite will only be built once per invocation of make, at most. If the same file is a prerequisite of multiple targets, and each of those targets has a different value for the same target-specific variable, then the first target to be built will cause that prerequisite to be built and the prerequisite will inherit the target-specific value from the first target. It will ignore the target-specific values from any other targets.

So I don't know how to force to recompile the objects in both rules (because these objects will depends on the included headers, of course...).
Is there a way to force the re-build of everything in the second rule ?

I'm working in a Linux environment (Redhat) using gcc.

Comment: I'd do it with two different build directories, each with its own Makefile which `includes` the main Makefile and adds the extra `CFLAGS`.  Use `VPATH` to locate the sources.